# query school elements using Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm looking for the correct way to query point/polygon elements that are

1. `name=*` but neither tagged as `amenity=school` **and** `building=school` tags; and
2. elements tagged as `building=school` but without a parent polygon that are tagged as `amenity=school` (to mark the school grounds)

I expect to see a list of nodes or ways that are tagged as `building=school`, but are not inside a closed way tagged as `amenity=school`. The purpose of the query is for Q&A of school-related elements in our region.

The following is the code I use to get the initial elements I'm interested in:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:25];
(
  node
    [name ~ "^.school.*$",i]["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."]({{bbox}});
  way
[name ~ "^.school.*$",i]["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."]({{bbox}});
);
//
// how to get parent poly for each resulting element?
//
// print results:
out body; 
>; 
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Does the surrounding way with `amenity=school` always have a `name=*` tag? If not, you cannot solve this with the official Overpass installation at this time.

Comment: For the first part of your question, please look up `!~` in the Overpass QL documentation.

Comment: @mmd , not always. the `amenity=school` may, or may not be present.  and we hope to improve the data where only buildings are tagged as schools, but not as as amenities.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. I was asking, if the surrounding `amenity=school` closed way always have a `name=*` tag. Now you replied that even the `amenity=school` may not be present. How should you determine, which closed ways are relevant then? Can you enhance your question a bit and provide some concrete examples?


Also, I'd recommend to discuss this topic on the tagging mailing list first and get some feedback, if this kind of data *improvement* is generally accepted procedure.

Comment: Some mappers, probably new ones, would map a school as:

`name=*`, `building=school`

They sometimes forget to add a polygon for the school grounds, thinking that the building tag is sufficient.

So the parent polygon for a school building, may or may not exist. I'm hoping to query for buildings tagged as schools, but without parent polygons that should've one marked as `amenity=school`. By the way, it's also possible to have buildings without school grounds in highly urban areas. 

Sorry for the inadequate explanation. English is not my first language.

Comment: That's in interesting question. We have a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/77) for a similar question, but your example doesn't fit into that schema easily. Will invetigate further in that ticket. - The issue here is that you amenity=school way doesn't always have a name...

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do about unnamed polygons. That's one thing we hope to correct if we can find these objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the closest possible approach is the following. It will return a number of false positives, because Overpass API doesn't have any `area` for ways with `amenity=school`, lacking a `name=*` tag.

```c
[out:json]
[timeout:25];

// Retrieve (surrounding) ways with amenity=school
way({{bbox}})[amenity=school];

// convert ways to area for later area query
map_to_area ->.area;

(
  // Determine difference of all school buildings in bbox
  // minus those inside the closed way with an amenity=school tag

  // All nodes+ways with building=school and no amenity=* tag in bbox
  (
    node ["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."]({{bbox}});
    way  ["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."]({{bbox}});
  );
- // except for
  (
    // All nodes+ways with building=school and no amenity=* tag in area
    node ["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."](area.area);
    way  ["building"="school"]["amenity"!~"."](area.area);    
  );
);

out geom;
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/der

Comment: I made a few modifications, but this got me very close to what I want to get out of OSM. Thank you.